# Inconsistency in extracting string representation of facts using clipspy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

Just started to work with clipspy-0.3.3 in Python 3.8.3.

When extracting facts, an inconsistency was encountered in the `.facts()` enumerator.

The code below

```
import clips

env = clips.Environment()

env.assert_string("(value 1)")
env.assert_string("(value 2)")
env.assert_string("(value 3)")
env.assert_string("(value 4)")
env.assert_string("(value 5)")
env.assert_string("(value 6)")
env.assert_string("(value 7)")
env.assert_string("(value 8)")
env.assert_string("(value 9)")
env.assert_string("(value 10)")

for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)
```

Produces result

```
(initial-fact)
(value 1)
(value 2)
(value 3)
(value 4)
(value 5)
(value 6)
(value 7)
(value 8)
(value 9)
f-10    (value 10)
```

from which one can see an inconsistency in which

- facts with number less than 10, the preceding `f-1`      is dropped away from the fact string, and,
- facts with number equal or greater than 10, the preceding `f-10`     is not dropped away from the fact string.

Even if the above inconsistency can be solved with regular expression substitution, as follow

```
import re

for fact in env.facts():
    print(re.sub(r'^[^(]*',r'',str(fact)))
```

would be nice if the string representation of facts would be returned consistently by the `.facts()` enumerator in `clispy` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `clipspy`, I would suggest you to open an issue on its [repository](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy).

Comment: Did it. The [content of the issue](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/issues/38) is practically same.